# Delete blanks/tabs between \url and normal text

Tags: spacing, url

```
\footnote{Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} am 27.07.2018 20:03}
```

generates this footnote:

[image: URL with spaces inbetween text]
How do I remove the tab or the blanks/spaces between "Quelle: " and the url and after the URL ends?

// EDIT: The package "url" is in use with option [spaces, obeyspaces].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It probably won't help you, but this is a general line breaking problem. TeX can only produce nicely filled if the text in the can be hyphenated properly and if there is enough whitespace to shrink and stretch. The URL is an unstretchable chunk and the date can not be broken, so you are left with subpar line breaks.

Comment: Please tell us more about your document setup. In particular, do you load either the `url` package or the `hyperref` package (or both)? If so, which which options do you load these packages?

Comment: Just the url-package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(updated the code used in the answer after the OP mentioned that the `scrreprt` document class is used)

I'd like to suggest that you consider two possible "fixes" to the excessive-whitespace issue:

- Insert `\raggedright` at the beginning of the argument of `\footnote`. This will produce a short first line in the footnote, but that's still much better than staring at excessive amounts of inter-word whitespace. (By the way, as @moewe has noted in comments posted below this answer, using `\raggedright` in footnotes can produce some rather bad outcomes if one of the KOMA-script document classes, such as `scrreprt`, is used. However, in the case of your document, the otherwise-deprecated option `bibtotoc` counteracts this bad tendency and footnote turns out to be OK. See @moewe's comments for more information.)
- Alternatively, do look into whether rewriting the footnote, even in a minor way, makes the over-stretching issue go away.

The following screenshot shows three footnotes. The first tries to replicate the screenshot you posted. The second employs `\raggedright`. The third differs from the first only in that the string `27.07.2018` is replaced with `27.\,7.\hspace{0pt}2018`. As you can see from the screenshot, allowing a line break between the month and year parts of the date string can have a huge effect on where the line break occurs -- and hence on how much interword whitespace is needed in the first line of the footnote.

[image]

Incidentally, while there's nothing wrong with loading the `url` package with the options `hyphens`, `obeyspaces`, and `spaces` (in fact, it's almost always a very good idea to do so!), specifying these options doesn't make a difference in the present case, since the problem is not related to LaTeX not being able to find a suitable line break in the URL string. Instead, the problem is related to the fact that LaTeX won't line-break the date string `27.07.2018`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,bibtotoc,abstracton]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[textwidth=14.1cm]{geometry} % trying to mimic the OP's setup
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\urlstyle{same} % to mimic the screenshot posted by the OP
\begin{document}

\footnote{Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} 
     am 27.07.2018 20:03}

\footnote{\raggedright Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} 
     am 27.07.2018 20:03}

\footnote{Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} 
     am 27.\,7.\hspace{0pt}2018 20:03}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: It is worth pointing out though that `scrartcl`'s `\footnote`s don't fare particularly well with `\raggedright` when one compares them to a non-ragged footnote. From the screenshots the line breaking the OP gets is very close to the defaults of `scrartcl` and not that close to `article` defaults. Of course I'm wildly speculating for lack of an MWE.

Comment: @moewe - Thanks. I'd also very much appreciate if the OP provided more information about which document class is in use (and related pertinent information)...

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,bibtotoc,abstracton]{scrreprt}

This is the document type + options. Thanks for your answer, I just read in the url doc, that you can use hypens?
What would you suggest?

Comment: @moewe - See the updated answer, made possible by the OP providing some much-appreciated additional pieces of information. I can't seem to make `\raggedright` produce a bad outcome with the footnote at hand. If need be, one could load the `ragged2e` package and use `\RaggedRight` instead of `\raggedright`, right? (pun intended! ouch!) A general benefit of using `\RaggedRight` (though not relevant for typesetting the OP's footnote) is that it doesn't prohibit hyphenation.

Comment: I got undesired output from `\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
\footnote{Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} am 27.07.2018 20:03}
\footnote{\raggedright Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} am 27.07.2018 20:03}
\footnote{Lorem ipsum}
\end{document}` The footnote with `\raggedright` starts too far out in the margin.

Comment: Aha. The deprecated `bibtotoc` sets `version=first`. If `version=last` (the default) is specified, I get the undesired behaviour. The behaviour changed between `version=3.21` and `version=3.22`.

Comment: @moewe - Many thanks for this in-depth analysis! I'll add a couple of sentences in the body of my answer to note that the OP's use of the `bibtotoc` option has some unexpected beneficial side effects. :-)

Comment: The question is whether or not we should ask Markus Kohm if this is a bug in the newer versions that should be fixed... I'm not sure if `\raggedright` at the beginning of a footnote is best practice ...

Comment: @moewe - My feeling is that regardless of whether or not using `\raggedright` (or `\RaggedRight`) in a footnote is best -- or even acceptable -- practice, it shouldn't create havoc. LaTeX should be able to typeset the footnote material properly irrespective of how (or even if) the material is justified. Do you want to contact Markus Kohm in this matter?

Comment: I posted a supplementary answer with a work-around for the new footnote definitions. Given that there is an interface to change the justification of the text I tend to think that the fact that `\raggedright` does not work is an accepted result of the new implementation. I don't know if `\raggedright` should even be used in `\footnote` and don't know enough about the internals. So I won't bother MK with this, but feel free to contact him about this if you feel more strongly about this or have reason to believe it should work.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of KOMA-Script (>=3.22) a new implementation of some footnote internals mean that `\raggedright` at the beginning of a  `\footnote` moves the footnote number to the right. The output is not particularly desirable so a simple `\footnote{\raggedright ....}` is ruled out, especially in combination with other non-`\ragged` footnotes.

```
\documentclass[version=3.23]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[textwidth=14.1cm]{geometry} % trying to mimic the OP's setup
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
\footnote{Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} am 27.07.2018 20:03}

\footnote{\raggedright Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} am 27.07.2018 20:03}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two footnotes at the bottom of the page: The marker and text of the second footnote starts a not insignificant distance to the right compared to the first footnote.]

The undesired behaviour is not visible in Mico's answer because the legacy option `bibtotoc` enables an older compatibility setting where the old footnote behaviour was still present.

Since version 3.23 KOMA-Script classes have a command called `\raggedfootnote` that can be used to set footnotes with different justification from the main text.

The settings are global, but you can restrict them to the next footnote only by enclosing them in a group. The MWE below uses `\RaggedRight` of `ragged2e` instead of `\raggedright`, but the same holds for `\raggedright`.

```
\documentclass[version=3.23]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[textwidth=14.1cm]{geometry} % trying to mimic the OP's setup
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
\footnote{Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} am 27.07.2018 20:03}

\begingroup
\let\raggedfootnote\RaggedRight 
\footnote{Quelle: \url{https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/BlacklistsAndWhitelists} am 27.07.2018 20:03}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: Two two-line footnotes at the bottom of the page: Footnote 1 is justified and has large spaces between the words in the first line. Footnote 2 is right aligned and does not have excessive white space between words, but of course the contents of the first line don't meet the right-hand margin, the line ends a good bit before the margin.]